# Is it incorrect not to decline "in" and "von" in dativ?

Tags: grammar, declension

I know both "von" and "in" are dative (in can also be accusative) prepositions and when there is an article either masculine or neutral, they are declined to "vom" and "im". Normally, when I speak German I say "von dem" and "in dem" without realizing it.

Is this declination grammatically mandatory? Or is it correct when someone like me says "von dem" or "in dem"?

Comment: They are not declined. They immerse the following article. Note that *declination* would result in ‘\*vo**m** einem Bild’ or other incorrect structures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a declension of *von* or *in*. It is a contraction and fusion of the preposition and the article together into a single word. Thus, the entire thing has nothing to do with grammar.

It is a feature more present in spoken and even more in colloquial language, where often other prepostions fuse in the following articles, too. To give just a very small number of examples:

- *in’n* from *in + den*
- *abm* from *ab + dem*
- *unters* from *unter + das*

These contractions are *never* mandatory, it is *always* possible to use the long form, e.g. to give emphasis. It is *not possible* to use them when dealing with relative pronouns, e.g:

> Das Lied, **von dem** ich gehört hab.

However, while never being mandatory, the forms *im* and *vom* are *so* common that they are even considered acceptable/encouraged in formal written language. So it would be *better style* to use them. In fact, especially *im* and *vom* are so common that not using them is often identified as an especially strong from of emphasis.

> A: Ich mag es, wenn es *in dem* Winter kalt ist.
> B: In welchem Winter?

(Example inspired by Carsten S in a comment. It is so unusual that one feels prompted to ask *which winter* since it is so close to *in diesem Winter*.)

---

We can distinguish between a declension and a contraction by the following thought experiment: Consider it to be a declension. Then, these forms should also turn up in some way when switching from a definite article to an indefinite one. However it is:

> Ich habe **im** Park eine hübsche Blume gesehen.
>
> Ich habe **in *einem*** Park eine hübsche Blume gesehen.

Comment: Wenn Ich „in dem Winter ist es kalt“ hörte, würde ich fragen, in welchem.

Comment: @CarstenS Was den Punkt »Betonung« meines Erachtens hervorhebt ;) Wie gesagt, ist nicht falsch, aber wer es hernimmt, sollte irgendeinen Grund haben, insbesondere bei *in* und *von*.

Comment: Dies ist die beste Antwort bisher. Ich würde (wie Carsten) ergänzen, daß die Verwendung der Langform anstelle der Kontraktion (*am/im/vom/beim*) leicht demonstrativ (deiktisch) klingt, wohl weil die Kontraktion fast immer verwendet wird, so daß die Langform so klingt, als wolle man auf etwas bestimmtes zeigen. Also klingt *in dem Winter* fast schon wie *in diesem Winter*, während *im Winter, im Sommer* das gleiche ist wie *winters, sommers*.

Answer (score 12):

It is *correct* in the sense that people will readily understand you, and are unlikely to correct you. However, in many constructions this will immediately mark you as a non-native speaker. In present-day usage, the contraction is so much more common than the theoretically 'normal' form that the full form now seems unusual:

> Im letzten *Spiegel* wurde berichtet...

(unremarkable)

> In dem letzten *Spiegel* wurde berichtet...

(slightly unusual)

Comment: FWIW, I *have* had Germans correct me when I've used the full form ;)

Comment: Also - it might be worth mentioning that the full form *is* compulsory in the case of relative pronouns. E.g. "Das ist der Park, in dem ich oft spazieren gehe."

Comment: Interesting what you pointed out. It will mark me as a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the liking of the person writing :

> Ich gehe in dem/ im Park herum.
>
> Ich habe eine Message von dem/ vom Mann erhalten.

Either way its correct. You can contract them or no. It depends on your liking.